# DataFrame columns sort by a given list and add empty columns for missing columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as below.

```
df =  pd.DataFrame(
    {  
       "code": ["AA", "BB", "CC","DD"],
        "YA" : [2,1,1,np.nan],
        "YD" : [1,np.nan,np.nan,1],
        "ZB" : [1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        "ZD" : [1,np.nan,np.nan,1]       
    }
)
```

Also, I have a sorting list.

```
sort_list = ['YD','YA', 'ZD', 'YB', 'ZA', 'ZB']
```

I am trying to add the missing columns based on the sort list and sort the DataFrame.

**expected output:**

```
   code YD  YA  ZD  YB  ZA  ZB
0   AA  1.0 2.0 1.0 NaN NaN 1.0
1   BB  NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   CC  NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   DD  1.0 NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN
```

I can get the result using the below code. Is there another(simple) way to do this?

**my code:**

```
col_list = list(set(sort_list) - set(df.columns.to_list()))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=col_list)
df1 = df1.fillna(np.nan)
df2 = df.join(df1, how='left')
df2 = df2.set_index('code')
df2 = df2[sort_list]
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try using `reindex`:

```
df = df.reindex(columns=['code'] + sort_list)
```

---

**df:**

```
    code    YD  YA  ZD  YB  ZA  ZB
0   AA      1.0 2.0 1.0 NaN NaN 1.0
1   BB      NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   CC      NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   DD      1.0 NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: You 're a genious, Pygirl!!!! Congrats!
I have been looking for this for soooo long.